# How to grab information from a url and use it in a php function?

Tags: php, mysql, url, sorting

I want to make a function that selects every field with a specific criteria. So basically I want to click on a link and let some part of that link tell my php function what the criteria for the selection is.

I have a list of links like this:

```
<li><a href="category.php?category=cat1">Cat1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Cat2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Cat3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Cat4</a></li>
<li><a href="">Cat5</a></li>
```

The part of the link is `.php?category=criteria`. How can I send this information to my function and use it to select the fields?

This is the function I have:

```
public function get_by_category ($cat) {
  $cat = $_GET['category'];
  $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Content WHERE category=?");
  $sql->bindParam(1, $cat);
  $sql->execute();

  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['Title'];
  }
}
```

The result is nothing, no errors etc. it doesn't know how to get the criteria because I don't know how to direct the criteria to it. How can I make this work? It's important that I could specify the criteria through the link.

Comment: @Mr.Radical not really: bindParam escapes the variables. That said, you are correct that the author should certainly be aware of how the $_GET is extremely insecure to use just like this.

Comment: @Mr.Radical
This is example code, I stripped it down to the bare essentials.

Comment: @berkes I wasn't aware PDO had this function build in. I usually work with the mysqli_ library.

Comment: @user1136934 I thought that this was example code. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PDO with named parameters usually works:

```
public function get_by_category ($cat) {
  $cat = $_GET['category'];
  $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * WHERE category=:category");
  $sql->bindParam("category", $cat);
  $sql->execute();

  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['Title'];
  }
}
```

You can see what SQL is being executed by placing a `print $sql->fullStmt` to inspect the prepared statement before it gets send to SQL.

Update: in order to see PDO exceptions, you can try-catch them:

```
public function get_by_category ($cat) {
  $cat = $_GET['category'];
  try {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * WHERE category=:category");
    $sql->bindParam("category", $cat);
    $sql->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }

  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['Title'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the $cat value to your query should do the job, but the link should be something like this:

```
<li><a href="category.php?category=15">Cat1</a></li>

public function get_by_category () {
  $cat = $_GET['category']; //Check if is numeric, strip code out of it etc..
  $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `category` = $cat");
  $sql->bindParam(1, $cat);
  $sql->execute();

  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['Title'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvote for introducing a gaping security hole: sql injection.

Comment: @berkes the issue here(read the question) is not security, but how to get this to work.

Comment: correct: but the original question example code was safe for SQL-injections, your suggestion introduces a new one. That is simply bad advice. Sorry.

Comment: correct: but the original question example code, is NOT working, so its pointless considering that it was safe for sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to mallix's answer, i'd recommend to change $cat on intval($cat) if category is numeric, or addslashes($cat), if category is string.